# Spring Boot Application faild to start in intellij idea showing exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to run application in Intellij Idea, but i am getting this error....

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'globalExceptionHandler': Lookup method
> resolution failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [com.app.exception_handler.GlobalExceptionHandler] from ClassLoader
> [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@2ad58620]
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1284)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> com.app.MmsApplication.main(MmsApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]

Following is the global exception handler class

```
package com.app.exception_handler;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.app.custom_exceptions.UserHandlingException;
import com.app.dto.ErrorResponse;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
    
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("in handle run time exc " + e);
        ErrorResponse resp = new ErrorResponse(e.getMessage(), LocalDateTime.now());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(resp);
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleEmptyDataExcetpion(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("in handle  exc " + e);
        ErrorResponse resp = new ErrorResponse(e.getMessage(), LocalDateTime.now());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(resp);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UserHandlingException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleUserHandlingException(UserHandlingException e) {
        System.out.println("in handle user exc " + e);
        ErrorResponse resp = new ErrorResponse(e.getMessage(), LocalDateTime.now());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(resp);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        System.out.println("in handle invalid meth args ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Validation Errors : ");
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(e -> sb.append(e.getDefaultMessage()+" "));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .body(new ErrorResponse(sb.toString(), LocalDateTime.now()));
    }
    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code snippet - applications starts just fine.

`IllegalStateException` signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.